# What is the purpose of the default /etc/securetty settings on Debian?

Tags: debian, login, pam

I created a Debian unstable container with `debootstrap` and ran it using `systemd-nspawn.service`.

I can log in as root with `machinectl login`, but not more than once at the same time.  When I run the second login, it refuses as soon as I enter `root`; it does not prompt for a password.

As you might expect, if I look at the system log, it says access was denied by `pam_securetty` because the tty `/dev/pts/2` "is not secure".  This raises several questions.

1. how is the first login `/dev/pts/0` considered secure??
2. why was `/dev/pts/1` not used on the second login?
3. The default /etc/securetty seems to list every type of tty - including serial lines which could be connected to modems??  I can imagine reasons for excluding pseudo-terminals.  But, if you're going to allow *all* the types of physical terminal, what's the point of this exercise?!  Why not work from a (short) set of tty types which are not allowed to login as root?  Is there anything that's been deliberately omitted from the list, that needs to be blocked by default apart from pseudo-terminals?  If there's a deliberate omission then why isn't it commented??

I was able to answer Q1.  The unspeakably horrible answer is that in Debian stretch (9-testing, `login-4.4-4`), /etc/securetty contains /dev/pts/0 and /dev/pts/1 but not /dev/pts/2.  One can guess this was added specifically to support `systemd-nspawn`.  And one would be [correct](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=830255).  But it only leaves me more confused about what these settings are supposed to accomplish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implication is the settings don't make any sense.

Obviously a distribution that supports serial installs would want to be able to allow the first serial console.  Your question is why the original Debian developer thought it was useful to leave pam_securetty enabled, but configure it to allow every type of tty.  And hence what would prevent a distribution from using a simpler setup.

Poettering suggests an answer: distributions *should* use a simpler setup, on the basis that the classification system used by securetty is obsolete.

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/852#issuecomment-127759667

> It comes from a time where tty names where static. But today the fewest ttys are actual good old mainboard serial ports. Pretty much all of them instead are plugged in via USB or are pseudo ttys. Either way their names are not fixed like /etc/securetty expects it, the entire concept is hence obsolete.
>
> Hence: please ask your distro to stop shipping with pam_securetty enabled by default, it's really a thing of the past. In the meantime remove it manually from all files in /etc/pam.d/* or add all your potential current and future ptys to /etc/securetty.

---

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/852#issuecomment-128564307

> You could just delete /etc/securetty from the container which will allow root login on all ttys.

Comment: See [#731656](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=731656), this is planned for Buster.